# Vue.js query flask results show on PC chrome but not android chrome ,opera, edge, while both work on firefox

Tags: python, vue.js

I am working on a Vue.js website trying to send a query from front-end to my flask backend，then search my data which is several docx documents to show some texts and pictures as search results on the screen。Somehow my codes work on PC chrome while not on android chrome，but both would work on firefox。 p.s. on dev mode

this is the search.vue for entering my query

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul v-if="searchResults.length">
      <li v-for="(result, index) in searchResults" :key="`result-${index}`">
        {{ result.filename }}
        <p v-for="(text, textIndex) in result.text" :key="`text-${index}-${textIndex}`">{{ text }}</p>
        <img 
          v-for="(image, imageIndex) in result.images" 
          :src="`/static/extracted_images/${image}`" 
          :alt="`Image ${imageIndex}`"
          :key="`image-${index}-${imageIndex}`" >
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      searchResults: [],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.query.q': {
      immediate: true,
      handler(newQuery) {
        this.query = newQuery || '';
        this.fetchSearchResults();
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    fetchSearchResults() {
  axios.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL}/api/search`, { params: { query: this.query } })
    .then(response => {
      this.searchResults = response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching search results:', error);
    });
}
  }
};
</script>
```

this is my back-end flask

```
@app.route('/api/search')
def search():
    search_query = request.args.get('query', '')
    directory = r"C:/Users/ID/Desktop/App/uploads"
    search_results = search_documents(directory, search_query)
    return jsonify(search_results)
```

function search_documents

```
def search_documents(directory, id_str):
    results = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".docx"):
            doc_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            extracted_data = extract_content(doc_path, id_str)

            # seperate text and images
            text = [item['content'] for item in extracted_data if item['type'] == 'text']
            images = [item['content'] for item in extracted_data if item['type'] == 'image']

            if text or images:  
                results.append({
                    'filename': filename,
                    'text': text,
                    'images': images
                })

    return results


def extract_content(doc_path, id_str):
    doc = Document(doc_path)
    extracted_data = []

    image_directory = r"C:/Users/ID/Desktop/vue.jsExample/Vue-3/MaidsPost/public/static/extracted_images"
    os.makedirs(image_directory, exist_ok=True)

    is_collecting = False

    #aquire texts
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        text = para.text.strip()

        if id_str in text:
            is_collecting = True
        elif "extracted_time: " in text and is_collecting:
            is_collecting = False

        if is_collecting:
            extracted_data.append({'type': 'text', 'content': text})
        
        # aquire images
        if is_collecting:
            for run in para.runs:
                print(para.runs)
                for shape in run.element.iter():
                    if shape.tag.endswith('blip'):
                        image_rid = shape.attrib['{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships}embed']
                        image_part = doc.part.related_parts[image_rid]
                        image_filename = f"extracted_image_{uuid.uuid4()}.png"
                        image_path = os.path.join(image_directory, image_filename)

                        with open(image_path, 'wb') as f:
                            f.write(image_part.blob)
                            extracted_data.append({'type': 'image', 'content': image_filename})
    
    return extracted_data
```

cleared browsing data on android

different css for screen sizes

I tried to rewrite extract_content() to see if different methods would work

tried rewrite search.vue's script

back-end does receive request so I tried printing out variables and it seems the problem is that images got lost in extract_content()，but I have tried using different methods to aquire images in extract_content() to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = para.text.strip().lower()
id_str = id_str.lower()
```

as it turns out, android chrome and others are somehow case sensitive here while working on windows chrome, so I changed these two lines and got results.